# Where can you find dividends for Australian Stock Market Shares (ASX) for more than 2 years of data?

Tags: dividends, australia, online-data-source, yahoo-finance

I've been using yahoo to get in some cases ten years worth of historical stock prices for stocks. I'm interested in the dividends that the stocks pay if any. Yahoo Finance don't show dividends.

But all I can find is the ASX page which shows the last two dividends, in this case: 
BHP, the ASX shows dividends at the bottom of the page for Sept 2013 and March 2014.

http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/companyInfo.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=bhp

[image]

I am looking for where possible more than the last two dividends, maybe the last 10 or 20 or 40.

**Does anyone know where to find information that shows more than the last two dividends for ASX shares?**

I would like to do some technical analysis on stocks which pay dividends.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to compile free information because the large providers are not yet permitted to provide bulk data downloads by their sources.  As better advertising revenue arrangements that mimic youtube become more prevalent, this will assuredly change, based upon the trend.

The data is available at money.msn.com.  Here's an example for [ASX:TSE](http://investing.money.msn.com/investments/stock-income-statement/?symbol=asx%3Atse).  You can compare that to shares outstanding [here](http://investing.money.msn.com/investments/stock-balance-sheet/?stmtView=Qtr&symbol=asx%3Atse).

They've been improving the site incrementally over time and have recently added extensive non-US data.  Non-US listings weren't available until about 5 years ago.

I haven't used their screener for some years because I've built my own custom tools, but I will tell you that with a little PHP knowledge, you can build a custom screener with just a few pages of code; besides, it wouldn't surprise me if their screener has increased in power.  It may have the filter you seek already conveniently prepared.

Based upon the trend, one day bulk data downloads will be available much like how they are for US equities on finviz.com.  To do your part to hasten that wonderful day, I recommend turning off your adblocker on money.msn and clicking on a worthy advertisement.  With enough revenue, a data provider may finally be seduced into entering into better arrangements.  I'd much rather prefer downloading in bulk unadulterated than maintain a custom screener.

money.msn has been my go to site for mult-year financials for more than a decade.  They even provide limited [10-year data](http://investing.money.msn.com/investments/financial-statements?symbol=asx%3Atse) which also has been expanded slowly over the years.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo provides dividend data from their `Historical Prices` section, and selecting `Dividends Only`, along with the dates you wish to return data for.

[Here is an example of BHP's dividends dating back to 1998](https://au.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=BHP.AX&a=00&b=29&c=1988&d=06&e=6&f=2015&g=v).

Further, you can download directly to `*.csv` format if you wish:

http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BHP.AX&a=00&b=29&c=1988&d=06&e=6&f=2015&g=v&ignore=.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can register with an online broker. You can usually join most online brokers for free and only have to fund your account if you decide to place a trade.

You may also check out the website of the actual companies you are interested in. They will provide current and historic data of the company's financials. For [BHP](http://www.bhpbilliton.com/home/investors/shareholderinfo/Pages/Dividends.aspx) you can click on the link at the bottom of this webpage to get a PDF file of past dividends from 1984.

Comment: So there is no like one website for dividend history for all australian stocks, you have to get them for each company manually!

Comment: Like I said in my answer you could join an online broker for free, as most would have this kind of information.